# mouseOver for NSTableView

Tags: xcode, nstableview

I have NSTableView in my application and i have added the hovering effect for the rows by using HoverTableDemo.

I can get the hovering effect only for one row in my table.

It is not apply for the whole table.

How can i get Hovering effect for full table.

Can any body have any idea please revert me.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look: https://stackoverflow.com/a/464828/1758762

You're on the right track with -mouseEntered: and -mouseExited:.

Look into NSView's -addTrackingRect:owner:userData:assumeInside: and -removeTrackingRect: methods.

```
I can get the hovering effect only for one row in my table.
```

You can either set up your tableView to create trackingRects for every row that's in there whenever the contents of the tableView change, or alternatively, set up/update one tracking area on the entire tableView whenever -tile or another layout related method is called.