# Is there any way to add mouseOver events to a tableView in cocoa?

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, nstableview

I want to make my tableView act like this:

When the mouse swipe over a certain row, the row will be highlighted, just like the mouseOver event of a button

Comment: I'm talking about Cocoa Application on mac, not ios ): @iPatel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Ignoring the "Mouse Over is bad GUI" sermon (which you'll ignore anyway… ;-))

```
#import "MoTableView.h"

@implementation MoTableView
{
    NSUInteger mouseRow;
    NSRect mouseRowFrame;
}

- (id)initWithFrame:(NSRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        // Initialization code here.
        mouseRow = -1;
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)awakeFromNib
{
    [self.window setAcceptsMouseMovedEvents:YES];
}

- (void)drawRect:(NSRect)dirtyRect
{
    [super drawRect:dirtyRect];

    // Drawing code here.
    [[NSColor redColor] set];
    NSLogDebug(@"mouseRowFrame: %@", NSStringFromRect(mouseRowFrame));
    NSFrameRectWithWidth(mouseRowFrame, 2.);
}

- (void)mouseMoved:(NSEvent *)theEvent
{
    NSPoint mouseLocation = [theEvent locationInWindow];
    NSPoint viewLocation = [self convertPoint:mouseLocation fromView:nil] ;
    NSInteger row = [self rowAtPoint:viewLocation];
    if (row != mouseRow) {
        mouseRowFrame = [self rectOfRow:row];
        [self setNeedsDisplay];
        mouseRow = row;
    }
}

@end
```

Comment: Don’t know what to tell you; just tried it and it worked fine for me. :(

Comment: Oh, I commented here and forgot. The above works for Cell-based TableView. I tried in View based. Later I was able to do it.

Answer (score 13):

It took me some time to work on it based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/464677/mouseover-in-nstableview) hint.

It works for me, correct me if I'm wrong.

Tested with Swift 3.0.2 on macOS 10.12.2 and Xcode 8.2.1

```
//
// Created by longkai on 30/12/2016.
// Copyright (c) 2016 xiaolongtongxue.com. All rights reserved.
//

import Cocoa

class InboxTableCellView: NSTableCellView {
    // MARK: - Outlets
    @IBOutlet weak var title: NSTextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var sender: NSTextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var time: NSTextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var snippet: NSTextField!

    // MARK: - Mouse hover
    deinit {
        removeTrackingArea(trackingArea)
    }

    private var trackingArea: NSTrackingArea!

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        self.trackingArea = NSTrackingArea(
            rect: bounds,
            options: [NSTrackingAreaOptions.activeAlways, NSTrackingAreaOptions.mouseEnteredAndExited,/* NSTrackingAreaOptions.mouseMoved */],
            owner: self,
            userInfo: nil
        )
        addTrackingArea(trackingArea)
    }

    override func draw(_ dirtyRect: NSRect) {
        super.draw(dirtyRect)

        NSColor(red: 0.96, green: 0.96, blue: 0.96, alpha: 1.00).set()

        // mouse hover
        if highlight {
            let path = NSBezierPath(rect: bounds)
            path.fill()
        }

        // draw divider
        let rect = NSRect(x: 0, y: bounds.height - 2, width: bounds.width, height: bounds.height)
        let path = NSBezierPath(rect: rect)
        path.fill()
    }

    private var highlight = false {
        didSet {
            setNeedsDisplay(bounds)
        }
    }

    override func mouseEntered(with event: NSEvent) {
        super.mouseEntered(with: event)
        if !highlight {
            highlight = true
        }
    }

    override func mouseExited(with event: NSEvent) {
        super.mouseExited(with: event)
        if highlight {
            highlight = false
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there any way to get the row's object and highlight the entire row? This answer almost works. But it only highlights the table cell and not the entire row.

Comment: Well, THAT was easy... thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You need to create a subclass and use tracking areas. That's what buttons do to track mouse hovering.

There's an Apple Sample Code that does exactly what you need - highlighting rows on hover:

[**HoverTableDemo**](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/samplecode/HoverTableDemo/Introduction/Intro.html)

It's been thoroughly discussed in [**WWDC 2011 Session 120**](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2011/index.php?id=120)